# how to display specific rows in sql

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have this rows in my table

```
Name    Grade        Comply
Alpha   2.5          NULL
Beta    Incomplete   NULL
Charlie Incomplete   3.0
Delta   1.5          NULL
```

I want to display only those with grades ex.(2.5,1.5) and grades with Incomplete but have value in comply column like charlie.

```
Name     Grade       Comply
Alpha    2.5         NULL
Charlie  Incomplete  3.0
Delta    1.5         NULL
```

Hope someone helps

Comment: You need a  `WHERE` clause. Use AND or OR between your conditions.

Comment: Please ask a specific question. If you don't know how to create SQL queries, please do a tutorial first, like https://sqlzoo.net/wiki/SELECT_basics

Comment: i know you need to use where clause but how can i display also charlie (for me it's quite difficult since some grades are also NULL when (where IN ('3.0','2.5','1.5') AND grade = 'Incomplete' AND compl IS NOT NULL

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT name, grade, comply
FROM table <tabname>
WHERE grade in ("2.5","1.5") 
OR (grade="Incomplete" and comply is not null);
```